# Evaluate the roots of Bhaskara’s formula

Tags: beginner, c, programming-challenge

I'm creating a program that finds the roots of Bhaskara’s formula and prints them.

I'm looking for advice to improve my logic more and more.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
        double os;
        double four;
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
        int robf;
        double x1;
        double x2;
        double qisma;
        double jidr;
        //int test;


        os = 2;
        four = 4;
        printf("Enter Number (a) : ");
        scanf("%d",&a);
        printf("Enter number(b) : ");
        scanf("%d",&b);
        printf("Enter number (c) : ");
        scanf("%d",&c);

        qisma = os*a;
        jidr = sqrt((double)(pow(b,os)-(four*a*c)));


        robf = pow(b,os)-(four*a*c);
        x1 = (-b+jidr)/qisma;
        x2 = (-b-jidr)/qisma;
        printf("%d\n",robf);

        if (robf > 0 || robf < 0)
        {
        printf("%s%f\n","Root1 = ",x1);
        printf("%s%f\n","Root2 = ",x2);
        }
        else
        {
                printf("it Imposible to find the roots cuz robf = \n");
        }

return(0);

}
```

Comment: "Bhaskara's formula" seems to be another name for the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 2):

> advice to improve my logic more and more.

**Provide link**

Rather than assume folks know of *Bhaskara’s formula*, provide a link, even in a code comment.

**Use an auto formatter**

Code lacks format consistency, betraying manual formatting.  Use an auto formatter for a more professional look.  Many IDEs incorporate them.

**Check return values**

User input is *evil*.  Do not assume valid numeric text was entered.

```
// scanf("%d",&a);
if (scanf("%d",&a) != 1) Handle_Error_or_other_TBD_code();
```

**Useless cast**

`(double)` serves no purpose in `sqrt((double)(pow(b,os)-(four*a*c)));`

Consider more direct coding.  Use `double` constants to ensure `double` math.

```
sqrt(1.0*b*b - 4.0*a*c);
```

**Define and initialize**

```
// double qisma;
...
// qisma = os*a;
// Instead
double qisma = os*a
```

**Don't repeat**

Don't repeat, Don't repeat.

```
    //jidr = sqrt((double)(pow(b,os)-(four*a*c)));
    //robf = pow(b,os)-(four*a*c);
    robf = pow(b,os)-(four*a*c);
    jidr = sqrt(robf);
```

**Guard against `sqrt(some negative)`**

Not later.

```
    robf = pow(b,os)-(four*a*c);
    if (robf < 0) TBD_Code();
    jidr = sqrt(robf);
```

**Avoid cancellation**

Consider the severe cancellation when  `jidr` near `|b|`.  The difference can incur severe lost of precision.

```
    //x1 = (-b+jidr)/qisma;
    //x2 = (-b-jidr)/qisma;
    
    // Alternative
    if (b < 0) {
      x1 = (-b+jidr)/qisma;
      x2 = c/x1;
    } else if (b > 0) {
      x2 = (-b-jidr)/qisma;
      x1 = c/x2;
    } else {
      x1 = jidr/qisma;
      x2 = -x1;
    }
```

**`()` not needed**

`()` here is [wet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#WET).

```
// return(0);
return 0;
```

**Avoid cancellation 2**

In *general*, `1.0*b*b - 4.0*a*c` is prone to cancellation.  That inexactness does not apply much here as `a,b,c` are integers.

When using `a,b,c` as `double`, code could use the more stable

```
double ac4 = 4.0*a*c;
if (ac4 > 0) {
  ac4 = sqrt(ac4);
  robf = (b + ac4)*(b - ac4);
} else {
  robf = b*b - ac4;
}
```

This is valuable when `b*b` is about `4.0*a*c`.

**Useless test**

`robf < 0` is worthless as prior code would have choked on `sqrt((double)(pow(b,os)-(four*a*c)))`.

**Excessive horizontal indenting**

IMO, 8 is a bit much.  Go with your group's coding standard.

**Better prompts**

```
// v  v--spelling           slang-v   v--obscure variable name
//"it Imposible to find the roots cuz robf = \n"
"It is impossible to find the roots because the discriminant is negative\n"
```

**Form a helper function**

Rather than code in `main()`, define a `int Bhaskara(double x[2], double a, double b, double c);`.

**Clean up**

What is `//int test;` in this post for?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you have been told never to use magic numbers, and have mistaken that advice:

> ```
>     double four;
>
>     four = 4;
> ```

The only place we use it is in calculating the discriminant (`4.0 * a * c`), but there it is a necessary part of the formula, not something that could ever be tweaked.  If it was really a magic number, then `four` is the worst possible name for it!

A worse instance of this is the use of `os` for two completely unrelated quantities that coincidentally happen to have the same value.  That's replicating exactly the problem that magic numbers cause - when two constants are the same, we want to know whether or not they have to be identical, or just happen to be so.

Also, we should use `const` for variables that should not change.

Comment: "variables that should not change" always _sounds_ wrong as variables are, well, variable. ;-)  Perhaps "for objects that should not change".